# Role Assignment to Resources on Azure

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-rbac

I am logged on to Azure using a Global Admin Account (account I signed up with). There I have created a resource group and it shows I have `Contributor` access. Why was I not assigned `Owner` Role instead? How did Azure assign that role to me when that resource group was created.

Answer (score 0):

You don't become `Owner` automatically but if you are a Global Admin, you can [elevate access](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/elevate-access-global-admin) to become a `User Access Administrator` on the root level (and all underlying subscriptions which are associated to the AAD tenant you are Global Admin at). And with this role, you can assign yourself the `Owner` role on the resource group. When a new resource group is created, Azure simply inherits the roles assigned to the subscription and management groups above so if you'd assign yourself the Owner role on a subscription, all resource groups that are created in this subscription will inherit you as an Owner.